# Why I've get [Not a URI because there is no client] is not a valid HTTP URL when trying to connect to API via OAuth2?

Tags: java, spring, api, oauth-2.0, spotify

I want to connect my Spring Boot application with Spotify API via OAuth2. In Postman I am correctly receiving token from Spotify but all I've got after calling my /main endpoint is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Not a URI because there is no client] is not a valid HTTP URL
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(UriComponentsBuilder.java:294) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.redirectUser(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:70) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-...
```

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuth2Configuration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/main").authenticated();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(
        OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.setOrder(-100);
    return registration;
    }
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2- 
autoconfigure:2.1.4.RELEASE'

testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.client-id=ID
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.client-secret=SECRET
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.scope=user-read-private,user-read-email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spotify.redirect-uri="http://localhost:8080/"

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.authorization- uri=https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.token-uri=https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.user-info-uri=https://api.spotify.com/v1/me
```

What I am doing wrong? Please help me I spend second day on it.

Comment: Inside application.properties, `spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.authorization- uri` there is a space in between and it shouldn't be authorization-uri? Is that by mistake?

Comment: Just here on StackOverflow, in file everything is allright, I fixed it finnaly by setting callback in Spotify Dashboard